# Why unit root test with D-F not using normal or t test?

Tags: time-series

Let $X_1, \dots , X_n$ be observations from the AR(1) model.

For large $n$, the maximum likelihood estimator $M(\phi_1)$ of $\phi_1$
is approximately normally distributed as

$N(\phi_1, (1−\phi_2)/n)$

For the unit root case, this normal approximation is no longer applicable, even asymptotically, which precludes its use for testing the unit root hypothesis

$H_0 : \phi_1 = 1$ vs. $H_1 : \phi_1 < 1$.

why? and why can't use t-student test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue is that when $X_t$ is a non-stationary process with a unit root, you can't apply the usual central limit theorems that imply convergence to the normal distribution: their assumptions are violated.

Instead, you can apply a functional central limit theorem, and it turns out the sample statistic doesn't even converge to a constant but rather a functional of Brownian motion: the test statistic converges to a random variable.

A much more thorough discussion than I can give is available here:
http://www.bauer.uh.edu/rsusmel/phd/ec2-5.pdf

As a practical matter, the Dicky-Fuller distribution has a somewhat bell curvish shape but with significant left skew.